# Fast, thread-safe Python ORM?

Tags: python, orm

Can you recommend a high-performance, thread-safe and stable ORM for Python? The data I need to work with isn't complex, so SQLAlchemy is probably an overkill.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are looking for something thats high performance, and based on one of your comments "something that can handle >5k queries per second". You need to keep in mind that an ORM is not built specifically for speed and performance, it is built for maintainability and ease of use. If the data is so basic that even SqlAlchemy might be overkill, and your mostly doing writes, it might be easier to just do straight inserts and skip the ORM altogether.

Comment: Thanks. I will also explore the possibility of switching to memcachedb for simple key-value pairs and fancy stuff like Cassandra for the rest if it will improve performance significantly without taking too much time to write.

Answer (score 7):

The [peewee orm](http://charlesleifer.com/docs/peewee/) is fast and extremely lightweight, might be a good fit if SQA is too heavy.

Answer (score 2):

SqlAlchemy's [SqlSoup](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/wiki/SqlSoup) module skips most of the tediousness of SqlAlchemy's mapping and session overhead. You can pretty much 'dive' straight in, take a look.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a more declarative layer on top of SQLAlchemy such as [Elixir](http://elixir.ematia.de/trac/wiki), or look at [Storm](https://storm.canonical.com/) which is also a bit more declerative than SQLAlchemy.

The latter was developed for and is used by sites such as Ubuntu/Canonical's [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/), so it should scale well.